# WPF RichTextBox's conditionally scroll?

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I've a `RichTextBox` in my app which is getting new content on certain events.
When new content is added, I'd like to scroll to the bottom, **only if** the scroll was at the bottom **before**.
How do I do this?
More specifically, the part that gives me trouble is determining the scroll position.

If it matters, the `RichTextBox` is using the default style and template, a few brushes changed or set to null, vertical scrollbar visibility is Auto and it's read-only.

Comment: Could you compare VerticalOffset to ViewportHeight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a rich textbox to auto scroll with new added text only when the scrollbar has been dragged to the bottom add the following class to your project

```
public class RichTextBoxThing : DependencyObject
{
    public static bool GetIsAutoScroll(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsAutoScrollProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsAutoScroll(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsAutoScrollProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsAutoScrollProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsAutoScroll", typeof(bool), typeof(RichTextBoxThing), new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback((s, e) =>
            {
                RichTextBox richTextBox = s as RichTextBox;
                if (richTextBox != null)
                {
                    if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                        richTextBox.TextChanged += richTextBox_TextChanged;
                    else if ((bool)e.OldValue)
                        richTextBox.TextChanged -= richTextBox_TextChanged;

                }
            })));

    static void richTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RichTextBox richTextBox = sender as RichTextBox;
        if ((richTextBox.VerticalOffset + richTextBox.ViewportHeight) == richTextBox.ExtentHeight || richTextBox.ExtentHeight < richTextBox.ViewportHeight)
            richTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
    }
}
```

then on any rich textbox that you want the auto scroll behaviour add the IsAutoSroll property

```
<RichTextBox ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" local:RichTextBoxThing.IsAutoScroll="True"/>
```

Comment: Same issue as the other answer. Doesn't work when the scrollbar just appeared.

Comment: Thank you! It works exactly as I'd expect it to now. I like this solution more than the other because it also gives me an example of using attached properties and shows me some properties of this control that I could use later. I didn't really know what to look for before.

Answer (score 3):

Much simpler condition to scroll is `VerticalOffset + ViewportHeight >= ExtentHeight`

Example:

```
bool shouldScroll = rtbx.VerticalOffset + rtbx.ViewportHeight >= 
                    rtbx.ExtentHeight;

// changes to RichTextBox 
// ...

if(shouldScroll) rtbx.ScrollToEnd();
```

Works also for the 'scrollbar just appeared' case.

Comment: This works great, but since your are comparing double that are likely to be equal, you should introduce an `epsilon` in your comparison. Basically I did `rtbx.VerticalOffset + rtbx.ViewportHeight >= rtbx.ExtentHeight - 1.0;` and it works well. I'm still up-voting since this saved me some time!

Answer (score 1):

You can basically do the following: Get the scrollbar, and subscribe to the changes of `Value`, `Maximum` and `Minimum` (they are all dependency properties). This way you can control the position in the code-behind by setting the `Value` to `Maximum` whenever you need to.

Now, how can you access the scrollbar? There are several ways. If you are sure which is the control template of your `RichTextBox`, you can get it using `GetTemplateChild(name)` (you get the name by examining the template in e.g. Blend). If you are not sure, you should better create your own template (again, Blend would give you a good template to start off) and applying it to the `RichTextBox` you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension method:

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void ScrollIfNeeded(this RichTextBox textBox)
    {
        var offset = textBox.VerticalOffset + textBox.ViewportHeight;
        if (Math.Abs(offset - textBox.ExtentHeight) > double.Epsilon) return;
        textBox.ScrollToEnd();
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
textBox.AppendText(// Very long text here);
textBox.ScrollIfNeeded();
```

**EDIT**: Alternative including scrolling to bottom when the scrollbar becomes visible:

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void ScrollIfNeeded(this RichTextBox textBox)
    {
        var offset = textBox.VerticalOffset + textBox.ViewportHeight;
        if (Math.Abs(offset - textBox.ExtentHeight) <= double.Epsilon)
        {
            textBox.ScrollToEnd();
        }
        else
        {
            var contentIsLargerThatViewport = textBox.ExtentHeight > textBox.ViewportHeight;
            if (Math.Abs(textBox.VerticalOffset - 0) < double.Epsilon && contentIsLargerThatViewport)
            {
                textBox.ScrollToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work before the scrollbar was visible. (before the content was larger than the available space)

Comment: No, because before the scrollbar is visible, the `VerticalOffset` is 0. You said you only wanted it to scroll to the bottom if it already was at the bottom...